# Rename the name of files in the folder with the help of Python Script, using name map from Excel sheet

Tags: python

There are many CSV files in a folder which I want it to be renamed. There is an excel sheet which contains name of files to be renamed to folder.

The files in folder are named as

```
TestData_30April.csv
TestData_20April.csv
TestData_18April.csv etc
```

while the excel sheet contains the name as

```
0.25-TestData_30April
0.98-TestData_20April
0.33-TestData_20April etc
```

Also first row in the excel sheet contains Header name while row 2 on wards contains the file name to be renamed.

My Aim is to rename

`TestData_30April.csv` to `0.25-TestData_30April.csv` similarly for all other files as well.

Here is the Code:

```
import os
import xlrd

#Excel Sheet containing name of files to be renamed in that folder
path="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test_Data\\Test_Summary.csv"

#Folder Containg all orginal file names
dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Wear_Data"

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

#In excel sheet column X or col_values(23) contains the file name to be renamed
print(sheet.col_values(23))  

list_of_filename_in_folder = [] # name of the files in the folder
list_of_filename_in_excel = [] #name of the files in excel
path_to_folder = ''  # base path of folder  
for name in list_of_filename_in_excel:
    excel_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder, name,'.csv')
    dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv' )
    if os.path.exists(dir_file_name):
        print('changing file name {} to {}'.format(name.split('-')[1],name))
        os.rename(dir_file_name, excel_file_name)
    else:
        print('no file {} with name found in location'.format(name.split('-')[1]+'.csv')








Here is the error
    dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv')

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What and where is the error?

Comment: dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,name.split('-')[1],'.csv')

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I saw this question few days ago - you have to check if `split('-')` gives 2 elements - `len( name.split('-') )`. If you get list with one element then you can't use `[1]` because it doesn't exists - and you get error `IndexError: list index out of range`. You could also check `print( name )` to see what name you have in variables and see if it has `-`.

Comment: you use `name.split('-')` three times - you could do it only once and then code will be more readable.

Comment: you could check if you have `-` in name using `print( name )`. You may also have char which looks like `-` but it has different code and for Python it is different char so it can't `split('-')`

Comment: How?? to modify it. Plz let me know, I am new to Python

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
for name in list_of_filename_in_excel:
    excel_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder, name,'.csv')
    newname = name
    if '-' in name:
        newname = name.split('-')[1]
    dir_file_name = os.path.join(path_to_folder,newname,'.csv' )

    if os.path.exists(dir_file_name):
        print('changing file name {} to {}'.format(newname,name))
        os.rename(dir_file_name, excel_file_name)
    else:
        print('no file {} with name found in location'.format(newname+'.csv')
```

Comment: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;